# how to get snap shots of touch part on screen by programming?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing iphone application in which I want to implement below features.
When user touch on iphone screen then user snap shot will generate of touch area of the screen and save to photo library.

I have done googling but dont get successed.

Please help me for this query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel , Pressing `Home and Sleep` button at the same time does a screen shot by default and saves it to Photo library

Comment: No not like that...Suppose i have open my application and i have kissed on my screen..then my lips will generated on the screen and save to photo album. like that

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for sample code to control the camera. Here is a [bare bones **Camera application that takes picture and saves it to library**](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/camera/camera-application-to-take-pictures-and-save-images-to-photo-album.html)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this method, pass the view touched to this method, will send u the image & save it to library.

```
- (UIImage*) giveScreentshotsOfView:(UIView*) view
{
if (view == nil)
    return nil;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.bounds.size);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
+ (UIImage *) captureView:(UIView *)view 
{

  CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];    
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(screenRect.size);    
  CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [[UIColor blackColor] set];
  CGContextFillRect(ctx, screenRect);

  [view.layer renderInContext:ctx];

  UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  //save the image to photo album

  UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil , nil);
}
```